# Image spriting in HTML emails?

Tags: html-email, css-sprites

I've done a bit of Googling and found no guidelines for doing image spriting in HTML emails. So I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it recommended? Are there benefits? Disadvantages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

inside e-mails you should use only very basic html, with basic inline styles. Mail client compatibilty is very different and poor (especialy outlook, wich is fairly common). I would definitly not use sprites in emails.

Comment: +1, just go back too good old HTML 4, that's the best practice for e-mails.

Comment: Actually, HTML 1.0 is a best practice for emails.  Keep in mind that image sprites are handled with CSS (via the background-image property) rather than HTML, and spriting is a method commonly used under the "HTML 4" paradigm.

A couple of good starting points for guideline information:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ |  
http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/

Comment: Sorry, meant to say XHTML 1.0... Doctype get stripped in many clients, but XHTML 1.0 Strict is automatically added in some.